# Add link to Help Center article about moderators in the moderators tab on the /users page

Tags: feature-request, moderators, users, help-center

The [moderators tab on the `/users` page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) has some information and links about moderating/moderators on Stack Exchange. I think it would make sense to add a link to the main Help Center article about moderators: [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](/help/site-moderators) - part of that content is already in the [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) blog post, but that has been updated/expanded and may be improved more in the future, while the blog post is not.